# How to show subtotal in vue app from firebase rtdb

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

I'm trying to fix this method in my vue app. It will take an array of objects that will contain the price of a selled item and needs to return the total calculation of all elements. The problem is that it will be wrong and it's not correct, into the db and console log I see the correct values, do I need to fix something in the code?

I'm saving the value that is taken from a v-model field correctly in firebase, probably I don't need the for loop?

```js
        showSubtotalSelled(items){
            let sum = 0
            for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                console.log(i)
                //if( items[i].sellPrice === items[i].selledItemsValue ){
                //  let parsed = items[i].sellPrice.replace(',', '.')
                //  sum = ( parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(parsed) ).toFixed(2)
                //} else {
                    let parsed = items[i].sellPrice.replace(',', '.')
                    console.log(parsed)
                    sum = ( parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(parsed) * items[i].pz ).toFixed(2)
                //}
            }
            if( sum === 0.00 ){
                return '0,00'
            } else {
                return sum.replace('.', ',')
            }
        }
```

This is the firebase rtdb scheme I'm using for the items

```js
-NJ_CNw4b8Yx1UZoNz_j
color: "GRIGIO"
id: 55
name: "TERRACES BULLDOG"
pz: "1"
sellPrice: "30,00"
size: "XL"
uid: "-NJ_CNw4b8Yx1UZoNz_j"
```

This is a sample of the document I load from rtdb. The calculation is 30€ more than the expected, I suppose there is something that is summed twice when the data are loaded and used to display the subtotal?

```js
  "articoliVenduti": [
    null,
    {
      "color": "NERO",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "SALERNITANA ZUCCOTTO TEAM",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "13",
      "size": "UNICA"
    },
    {
      "color": "GRANATA",
      "id": 2,
      "name": "SALERNITANA FELPA TECH",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "80",
      "size": "XL"
    },
    {
      "color": "GRANATA",
      "id": 3,
      "name": "SALERNITANA TRAPUNTA",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "55",
      "size": "UNICA"
    },
    {
      "color": "GRANATA",
      "id": 4,
      "name": "SALERNITANA MAGLIONE NATALIZIO",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "45",
      "size": "L"
    },
    {
      "color": "MAZZOCCHI",
      "id": 5,
      "name": "SALERNITANA MAGLIA GARA THIRD 2022/2023",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "95",
      "size": "M"
    },
    {
      "color": "BLU NAVY",
      "id": 6,
      "name": "LYLE SCOTT SOFTSHELL JACKET",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "130",
      "size": "L"
    },
    {
      "color": "BLU NAVY",
      "id": 7,
      "name": "TERRACES CAPPELLO LANA",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "30",
      "size": "UNICA"
    },
    {
      "color": "GIALLO",
      "id": 8,
      "name": "TERRACES CAPPELLO LANA",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "30",
      "size": "UNICA"
    },
    {
      "color": "GRIGIO",
      "id": 9,
      "name": "TERRACES FELPA ZIP",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "65",
      "size": "XL"
    },
    {
      "color": "BLU NAVY",
      "id": 10,
      "name": "TERRACES TESCHIO",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "30",
      "size": "XL"
    },
    {
      "color": "GRIGIO",
      "id": 11,
      "name": "TERRACES BULLDOG",
      "pz": "1",
      "sellPrice": "30",
      "size": "XL"
    }
  ]
```

NB: To be more clear, data are saved correctly in rtdb, it's not there the problem, but I need to show on the vue front-end the exact calculation of all selled items that are loaded from rtdb.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little bit more about what are you trying to resolve? you didn't mention how are you saving the values at rtdb.

Comment: the values are pushed using `push()` of rtdb sdk methods. This will ensure that no value are overwrited, I previously had an incremental id based on the lenght but it will fail so I've used the rtdb method. I'm trying to do a calculation of the total value of selled items

Comment: if problem is only in this function it would be great if you can provide what is inside your `items` array, so we can play around with data.

Comment: @NehaSoni please see the updated question with a sample of the data

Comment: If I take your sample data and run the calculation program you created, the total is 603, which is correct, right? So, where is the issue, am I missing something?

Comment: I've done the calculation using the calc app of the mac but is incorrect what is dispayed. I saw a wrong calculation on the screen, the correct one is 623,50 and I get 653,50

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function :

```js
const arr = [{"color": "NERO", "id": 1, "name": "SALERNITANA ZUCCOTTO TEAM", "pz": "1",    "sellPrice": "13", "size": "UNICA"}, {"color": "GRANATA", "id": 2, "name": "SALERNITANA FELPA TECH", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "80", "size": "XL"}, {"color": "GRANATA", "id": 3, "name": "SALERNITANA TRAPUNTA", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "55", "size": "UNICA"}, {  "color": "GRANATA", "id": 4, "name": "SALERNITANA MAGLIONE NATALIZIO", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "45", "size": "L"}, {"color": "MAZZOCCHI", "id": 5, "name": "SALERNITANA MAGLIA GARA THIRD 2022/2023", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "95", "size": "M"}, {"color": "BLU NAVY", "id": 6, "name": "LYLE SCOTT SOFTSHELL JACKET", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "130", "size": "L"}, {"color": "BLU NAVY", "id": 7, "name": "TERRACES CAPPELLO LANA", "pz": "1",   "sellPrice": "30", "size": "UNICA"}, {"color": "GIALLO", "id": 8, "name": "TERRACES CAPPELLO LANA", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "30", "size": "UNICA" }, {"color": "GRIGIO", "id": 9, "name": "TERRACES FELPA ZIP", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "65", "size": "XL"}, {  "color": "BLU NAVY", "id": 10, "name": "TERRACES TESCHIO", "pz": "1", "sellPrice": "30",  "size": "XL"}, {"color": "GRIGIO", "id": 11, "name": "TERRACES BULLDOG", "pz": "1",  "sellPrice": "30,85", "size": "XL" } ]
function showSubtotalSelled(items){
  return items.reduce((a, b) => a + +b.sellPrice.replace(',', '.'), 0)
}   

console.log(showSubtotalSelled(arr))
```

Comment: need to test also this way, at the moment in the sample I think is missing an item, but in production a have a difference on the calculation and it's about 30€, so I don't know what is wrong in the vue rendering process

Comment: I've tested, but I have the same problem, wrong calculation. At this point I think there is a problem with the data user entered because the caluculation I've used and also the reduce will do the same calculation? I've added a sample of the db I have now, please see the updated question